# How to use Modules/Classes in Typescript with Requirejs

Tags: typescript, requirejs, dynamics-crm

I'm attempting to start using RequireJs from within MS CRM, but I'm confused as to how to use Require JS with my current TypeScript files.

Currently, each form in CRM has it's own Typescript file, that looks something like this:

```ts
// File Path .\_Contoso\scripts\Contact.ts
module Contoso {
    export class Contact {

        private static instance = new Contact();

        //#region Form Properties

        static fields = { }

        //#endregion Form Properties

        //#region onLoad / onSave

        static onLoad(): void {
            Contact.instance.onLoad();
        }

        private onLoad = (): void => { ...}

        static onSave(): void { Contact.instance.onSave(); }

        private onSave = (): void => { ... }

        //#endregion onLoad / onSave
    }
}
```

Each file may contain dependencies on one or more common files/classes:

```ts
// File Path .\_Abc\scripts\CommonLib.ts
module ABC_Corp {
    export class CommonLib {
        ... 
    }
}

// File Path .\_Abc\scripts\RestLib.ts
module ABC_Corp {
    export class RestLib {
        ... 
    }
}


// File Path .\_Abc\scripts\RoleLib.ts
module ABC_Corp {
    export class RoleLib {
        ... 
    }
}
```

These files all currently live in a VS Website Project.  Whenever I save the ts files, it generates the JS and I deploy those files to CRM.

Now, enter RequireJS.  Since the only supported hook in CRM for JS file execution to begin is the "OnLoad" and "onSave" events, I have created a Contoso.Require file that will read the require configuration from the CRM OnLoad function call, and then call the appropriate onLoad method on the form script.  This is all working in order to load the main form JS, and call the onLoad function.  My problem is I have to define in the CRM OnLoad Event, the required JS files, rather than having each file define what files are required by it.   How do I define what files are required by each class/file?

Comment: I'm not really sure of the question but hopefully it becomes clear with some back-and-forth. Anywhere you are going to use require.js you need to explicity include require.js. So in the case of a CRM form you'll have to add a reference to require.js and to contact.js. In coding contact.js you add `///<reference path="require.d.ts" />` (with the correct pathing) and then in your OnLoad function you can use `import somemodule = require('./somemodule');` (again with correct pathing.) I'm missing something, I think, from your question - but hopefully it gets clearer with some back-and-forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> rather than having each file define what files are required by it.

You still need to do that. Because that is what is going to drive the *ordering*.

But now instead of using `module` (which are now called namespaces) use the `import/export` format to use *true modules*.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: So I'll need to switch to AMD Typescript Compilation, and then I'll need to export my modules and import them for each file?  I already have javascript comments for it, so I could probably run through and do a search and replace.  Just want to make sure I'm barking up the right tree...